# Watch function triggered for different array key than selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I prevent the watch function from being triggered for a key other than the one selected in the data array?

```js
import { useSessionStorage } from "@vueuse/core";

const defaultState = {
  data: [
    { key: 1, name: "A" },
    { key: 2, name: "D" },
    { key: 3, name: "C" },
  ]
}

const state = useSessionStorage("settings", defaultState, {
  mergeDefaults: true,
});

const key0Name = toRef(
  () => state.value.data[0].name
);
watch(key0Name, (newOpts) => {
  console.log("key0Name", newOpts);
});

state.value.data[0].name = "Z" // Triggers watch function.
state.value.data[1].name = "Z" // Also triggers watch function.
```

Comment: What if you just pass the function to `watch()` instead of using `toRef()`?

Comment: Updating `data[1].name` does not trigger the watch when I test it in [this Vue SFC playground](https://shorturl.at/dDEGQ)

Comment: Sorry you guys missed the update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have to use toRefs on the array of objects.

```
const data = toRefs(state.value.data);

watch(data[0], ...)
```

And if I want to watch the name:

```
const name0 = toRef(data.name)

watch(name0, ...)
```

I think what's happening is the state is a ref but the properties are regular js objects.  So we need toRefs and toRef to setup a two way data bind with those properties.  You can freely pass the state vars directly to child components and see their changes using these refs.